What would an animal living and migrating with a perpetual storm look like?
Basically, I got these things called Stormstokers, which, by way of magic, maintain and inhabit storms. They migrate with these storms, guiding the storms along ley lines so they don't run out of magic. They can inhabit various kinds of storms, with different regional variants showing preference for different storms. They move in flocks, and basically spend their entire lifecycle inside a very violent storm, hunting any animal unfortunate enough to get caught in the storm. What are some adaptations that might come as a result of these conditions to help navigate storms better?

What are they able to do, those Stormstokers? Are they amorph or do they have eyes, hands, legs maybe? How big are they? Do you mean literal ley lines or magic ones that are invisible?

The magic part is irrelevant to their actual appearance because of how the system works. They evolved like any other animal. I don't have any guidance for how they should appear, I just want to know what an animal under these conditions would naturally evolve to look like The ley lines are magical yes, but they are found along fault lines as the result of a big ol spirit sleeping in the core of the earth, so generally mountainous regions/oceans. They're not restricted to these regions, but this is where they are generally found.

It's really up to you. It's like asking "what would an animal living in the forest look like" and the answer is "look at how many different animals live in the forest". You could ask after adaptations that would be beneficial for storm life, as you do in your last sentence, but there isn't much to answer beyond "has wings, is waterproof, and is relatively tough".

One issue that they need to consider is how storms develop and dissipate. While some cold low pressure systems can persist for many days and travel over long distances, many of them generate multiple storms that start, rain hard, and disappear.

How a creature develops over geological time is a combination of various things: 1) The environment in which they evolved (yes, including the magic). 2) The balance of the ecosystem's pressures on them (re.: food/resource gathering/availability, predation). 3) Sexual selection. 4) Group selection (group acceptance, crowding). 5) Random beneficial (or no-too-detrimental) mutation.  - Without giving us explicit details of each domain, there's no chance we'd even get to the random mutation part. Presumably eg., their mouthparts are adapted to eating what they eat (plethora of designs there) etc..

I'm the last VTC and I'd like to explain why. You have creatures that exist due to magic that permanently inhabit a condition that has no terrestrial equivalent. In otherwords, they can look like anything and can have any characteristic you want. Thanks to the magic, biology and evolution are entirely irrelevant. Note, however, that removing the magic from your Q doesn't save it. It just shifts my "too story-based" vote to "opinion-based" or "not WB as defined in the [help]" due to no answer being any better than another (brainstorming). Should it look like a flying fish or a flying squirrel?

Given that it's magic, the creature can realistically be anything, but I'll give you some food for thought to consider from a more biological perspective.
The first thing that comes to mind, given that they guide the storm, is that they live in the clouds themselves. They could, through magic, generate some large amount of static electricity, which could, when amassed into a flock, provide some sort of pull. To store static electricity, perhaps they have hundreds of hairlike structures, something hard and bristly so that the dampness of the atmosphere doesn't slick it down.
A hairy creature that can fly seems somewhat reminiscent of a bat. Given that they're predators, I like the idea that they hide in the clouds, and swoop down upon seeing prey. I think, given how noisy storms tend to be, they would nearly entirely rely upon their eyesight rather than hearing. This hunting style would be reminiscent of a hawk or eagle, but they wouldn't have a nest to return the catch to and eat the prey, so either they would eat the animal on the ground, or more interestingly, carry it back up to break it up with the flock, so they each have a morsel they can eat as they glide. A group behavior could then develop, where each storm stoker hunts one at a time in a rotation.
Perhaps, for a better element of surprise, the storm stokers can use the bristles on their hair to sense an impending lightning strike. They could time, or even trigger, a lightning strike for when they swoop, so that they can hide themselves from their prey. Or maybe on the top of their wings (which would be facing away from the ground) are highly reflective plates, which catch the light and make a flash that appears from a distance to be a lightning strike when they swoop, albeit without the impending thunder.
These stormstokers would have to be quite huge to catch, carry, and eat larger prey. To reproduce (if they don't just magic into existence), perhaps the alpha female of the flock could bare the litter, and the females lower on the social hierarchy would grab hold to share the weight of the gestating babies as they fly. Or, instead of a mammalian birth, they could lay eggs which they carry. To make sure that the babies are fully mature and capable of flying in the storm, we could give these creatures a marsupial sack that they can hold the young/eggs in.

Pack hunting amphibians would work. Constant rain is fine and when the storm moves over water they'll still be ok. Perhaps the size of large crocodiles.
Most animals find refuge from storms, birds don't fly around in them, they fly ahead of them or hunker down wherever they can.
Alternatively large pack hunting otter like creatures. Or any animal that can handle water and land and defend itself while getting food. I say pack hunting as storms are quite localised and they need access to mates which will be a problem if they're solitary animals.
Flying animals can't handle storms and land bound ones can't traverse much water and still get food while they do so.
Storms would be absolutely terrifying if there were packs of beasts hunting in them as well as the dangers inherent in storms already. Especially to small animals.
